# Need help figuring out how to plot numerical simulations of ODEs onto plot of analytical solutions in R

Tags: r, simulation, ode, numerical-integration

I'm working on some phytoplankton resource-use models. I'm still fairly new to coding. I have 3 ODEs for this model where N = population, S = external resource concentration (i.e how much phosphorus is in the water around the phytoplankton), and Q = the internal resource quota (i.e how much phosphorus is stored in the phytoplankton's body at one time) I have the analytical solutions here:

```
q <- function(g, r, d) {
  (g*r)/(r-d)
}

s <- function(g, r, d, k, v) {
  -(d*g*k*r)/(d*g*r+d*v-r*v)
}

n <- function(d, r, s0, g, k, v) {
  (d - r)*(-1*(s0/(g*r)) - (d*k)/(d*g*r + d*v - r*v))
}
```

And the code for their graphs corresponding graphs, where d is the dilution rate (controls growth rate):

```
curve(q(r = 0.1, d = x, g = 0.4), xlab = "dilution rate", ylab = "quota", 0.1,0.49)
curve(s(r = 0.5, d = x, g = 0.4, k = 0.02, v = 0.01), xlab = "dilution rate", ylab = "resource concentration",0.1,0.49)
curve(n(r = 0.1, d = x, g = 0.001, k = 0.01, v = 0.1, s0 = 1), xlab = "dilution rate", ylab = "concentration of species", 0.1, 0.49)
```

So for the numerical simulation, I used deSolve:

```
one <- function (t, x, params) {
  ## first extract the state variables
  N <- x[1]
  Q <- x[2]
  S <- x[3]
  ## now extract the parameters
  r <- params["r"]
  g <- params["g"]
  d <- params["d"]
  v <- params["v"]
  k <- params["k"]
  s0 <- params["s0"]

  
  ## now code the model equations
  dNdt <- N*(r*(1-(g/Q))-d)
  dQdt <- v*(S/(S+k))-r*(Q-g)
  dSdt <- d*(s0-S)-(N*v*(S/(S+k)))
  ## combine results into a single vector
  dxdt <- c(dNdt,dQdt,dSdt)
  ## return result as a list!
  list(dxdt)
}
parms <- c(r=0.1, g=0.001, d=0.03, v=0.1, k=0.01, s0=1) 
times <- seq(from=0,to=1000,by=0.01)
xstart <- c(N=800,Q=1,S=1)

ode(
  func=one,
  y=xstart,
  times=times,
  parms=parms,
) %>%
  as.data.frame() -> out

out %>%
  gather(variable,value,-time) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=time,y=value,color=variable))+
  geom_line(size=2)+
  theme_classic()+ 
  labs(x='time',y='?')
```

So my goal is to try to get the numerical solutions to be similar to the analytical solutions. My advisor said I should take the last values for N, Q, and S from the numerical simulation (the equilibrium) and vary some of the parameters (such as dilution rate) and plot those on the graph of the analytical solutions. He mentioned something about a for loop, but I'm just a little confused as to how to go about it. I would love some help figuring out how to set up the for loop with the ODE.

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of using the last values of N, Q or D, you can also use `runsteady` from package **rootSolve**. An example can be found [here](https://tpetzoldt.github.io/chemostat/chemostat-ode.html).

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, it may be more natural to use `expand.grid` and `apply` instead of a `for` loop:

```r
## List of parameter values
l <- list(r = seq(0.1, 0.5, length.out = 11L), 
          g = seq(0.01, 0.05, length.out = 11L),
          d = 0.03,
          v = 0.1,
          k = 0.01,
          s0 = 1)

## Data frame with 'prod(lengths(l))' rows listing combinations
## of parameter values
P <- do.call(expand.grid, l)

## Wrapper around 'ode' extracting state at final time
getLast <- function(parms, y, times, func, ...) {
    X <- deSolve::ode(y, times, func, parms, ...)
    X[nrow(X), -1L]
}

## Data frame corresponding rowwise to 'P' listing final states
X <- as.data.frame(t(apply(P, MARGIN = 1L, FUN = getLast, 
                           y = c(N = 800, Q = 1, S = 1), 
                           times = seq(from = 0, to = 1000, by = 1),
                           func = one)))

## Putting everything together with analytical solutions
d <- transform(cbind(P, X), 
               N_exact = n(d, r, s0, g, k, v),
               Q_exact = q(g, r, d),
               S_exact = s(g, r, d, k, v))
head(d)
```

```
     r    g    d   v    k s0        N          Q            S  N_exact    Q_exact      S_exact
1 0.10 0.01 0.03 0.1 0.01  1 69.99699 0.01428571 4.304161e-05 69.99699 0.01428571 4.304161e-05
2 0.14 0.01 0.03 0.1 0.01  1 78.56842 0.01272727 3.832816e-05 78.56842 0.01272727 3.832816e-05
3 0.18 0.01 0.03 0.1 0.01  1 83.33032 0.01200000 3.613007e-05 83.33032 0.01200000 3.613007e-05
4 0.22 0.01 0.03 0.1 0.01  1 86.36063 0.01157895 3.485793e-05 86.36063 0.01157895 3.485793e-05
5 0.26 0.01 0.03 0.1 0.01  1 88.45853 0.01130435 3.402844e-05 88.45853 0.01130435 3.402844e-05
6 0.30 0.01 0.03 0.1 0.01  1 89.99699 0.01111111 3.344482e-05 89.99699 0.01111111 3.344482e-05
```

Plotting the equilibrium value of `N` as a function of `r` and `g`, the two parameters that we've allowed to vary:

```r
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(d, aes(x = r, colour = factor(g))) + 
    geom_point(aes(y = N)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = N_exact))
```

[image]

Comment: WOW thank you! Would you be able to advise me on the best way to go about plotting that, especially plotting that onto my analytical solution graphs? I made the cbind(P, X) in to a data frame but am kind of unsure where to go from there.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example. You'll find several `ggplot2` tutorials out there, if you want to understand how the plot was created from the data frame.

Comment: So I've modified the code a little bit to model one species, two resources (mostly just adds two more state variables and a handful of extra parameters. When I try to use   `N <- t(apply(K, MARGIN = 1L, FUN = getLast, 
             y = c(N=1,Q1=0.5,Q2=1,S1=100,S2=500), 
             times = seq(from = 0, to = 1000, by = 0.1),
             func = two))` It fills in with a bunch of NA values. Do you have any ideas of why that could be?